# php api rest does not accept cors requests even using header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Tags: php, angular, cors

I'm creating an angular application 6 and api rest in php.
when my angular application tries to perform a request the following url: `http://localhost/bdevApi/api/index/categoryexame?page=1` 
the following error is loaded:

> Failed to load Response to preflight request doesn't pass access
>   control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:4200`' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

The angle is in port 4200 and my api is in 80

I visualized some tutorial and added the following header to my api

**api/index.php**

```
  <?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

    include("config/config.php");
    include("import/Interpreter.php");
    include("import/SendJson.php");
    include("database/Connection.php");
    include("import/AuthToken.php");

    $db = Connection::getInstance();

    if( $db->getStateConnection() )
    {
        $arrayHeader = getallheaders();
        $token = isset($arrayHeader["token"]) ? $arrayHeader["token"] : ""; 

        // Recupera dados via Json
        $strJson = file_get_contents('php://input'); //echo $strJson;
        $jsonObject = json_decode($strJson); //var_dump($strJson);


        $Interpreter = new Interpreter(
            "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]", 
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
            $jsonObject
        );

        if(AuthToken::validateToken($token))
            $Interpreter->initializes(true);
        else
        {
            if($token == "") 
                $Interpreter->initializes(false);       
            else
            {
                $S = new SendJson();
                $S->Send("200", "1", "Token não autenticado", null);
            }   
        }
        $db->closeConnection();
    }

    ?>
```

How do I get my application to accept these headers and not show this error?

[EDIT]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAWGe.png)

new error

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost/bdevApi/api/index/categoriaexame?page=1: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: Did u check in chrome debugger the response body and headers  for the OPTIONS request? If it's  Options your server should return 200 straight away. Maybe it's going through the rest of the code and returning something else

Comment: I do not understand this very well, I just went on Network Headers and there it is Request Method: OPTIONS, Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: That's a good start. There is also a  response  body tab normally. Nothing there for the OPTIONS request?

Comment: in my response headers it says that the status is 200 but I can not find anything referring to options

Comment: Do you want me to take a print out of my network and put it in my question?

Comment: Yes if you could do that. Showing request and response headers

Comment: @David I added this code ShahriatHossain now the error has changed and in the network part I can already see the data that my server sends, but I still can not receive in the application

Comment: Are you running this on windows or *nix system? The way to resolve this issue forever is to have PHP and JS run under the same domain. It's achieved by creating a reverse proxy in your web server that passes certain requests to node server which runs your .js files.

Comment: Hello, i am execute in windows localhost using wamp in port 80 and angular port 4200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because of cross origin policy. You can go through this document to get the details knowledge about CORS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control

You can try this code below:

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I was able to load the data into netword but it was not yet for the application